# Elasticsearch array only contains query

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I've data in this format:

```
{
  "id": "doc0",
  "tags": ["a", "b", "c"]
}

{
  "id": "doc1",
  "tags": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
}

{
  "id": "doc2",
  "tags": ["a", "b"]
}
```

I need to form an ES query that fetches only documents that contains both "a", "b" and nothing else.

If I write a terms query, it matches all the documents, as all documents have both "a" and "b" but only one document has nothing else apart from "a" and "b"

What is the best way to form this query? I don't have the list of the other values to add "not_contains" clause.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways in which you can achieve your result :

1. You can use a combination of [bool query(with `must` and `filter` clause) and script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) to retrieve only those documents that have both "a" and "b".

**Index Data:**

```
POST testidx/_doc/1
{
  "id": "doc0",
  "tags": ["a", "b", "c"]
}

POST testidx/_doc/2
{
  "id": "doc1",
  "tags": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
}

POST testidx/_doc/3
{
  "id": "doc2",
  "tags": ["a", "b"]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
POST testidx/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "tags": "a"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "tags": "b"
              }
            },
            {
              "script": {
                "script": {
                  "source": "if(params.input.containsAll(doc['tags.keyword'])){return true;}",
                  "lang": "painless",
                  "params": {
                    "input": [
                      "a",
                      "b"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "testidx",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "doc2",
          "tags" : [
            "a",
            "b"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

2. You can use [`minimum_should_match_script` param with terms set query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html#terms-set-field-params). When compared to a script query, Terms set query will be faster.

[image]

```
POST testidx/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "terms_set": {
          "tags": {
            "terms": [
              "a",
              "b"
            ],
            "minimum_should_match_script": {
              "source": "doc['tags.keyword'].size()"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "script": {
                "script": {
                  "source": " return doc['k1.keyword'].size() == 2;",
                  "lang": "painless"
                }
              }

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Terms Set](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html) query.

Before using teams set query, you need to update your index document with number of elements count in one field.

```
PUT sample1/_doc/1
{
 "id": "doc0",
  "tags": ["a", "b", "c"],
  "required_matches": 3
}
PUT sample1/_doc/2
{
  "id": "doc1",
  "tags": ["a","b","c","d"],
  "required_matches": 4
}
PUT sample1/_doc/3
{
  "id": "doc2",
  "tags": ["a","b"],
  "required_matches": 2
}
```

Query:

```
POST sample1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms_set": {
      "tags": {
        "terms": [ "a", "b"],
        "minimum_should_match_field": "required_matches"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```json
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.17161848,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "sample1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.17161848,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "doc2",
          "tags" : [
            "a",
            "b"
          ],
          "required_matches" : 2
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: These are minimum should match, it can match greater count, too.. Right?

Comment: No, it will not match because number of element in your documents and value which you are sending in query always same. in your exmaple only, you have greter number for doc0 and doc1 but it is not coming in result right. Dont confused with `minimum_should_match_field` and `minimum_should_match`